# function st_intersects() does not exist using PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial, postgresql-9.3

I have a table as shown below with three columns.

**Table**: geomet

```
create table geomet
(
cola float,
colb float,
geopath geometry
);
```

**Insertion of records**:

```
insert into geomet values('12.32232442','43.2324535',point(12.32232442,43.2324535)::geometry);
```

I have this:

```
select * from geomet;

cola          colb         geopath
---------------------------------------------------------------------
12.32232442   43.2324535   01010000004F34D5B407A528409D2B4A09C19D4540
```

**Note**: I need to find the Intersect of column `geopath` in my table as shown above. I have also installed `PostGIS`.

So I have tried this:

**Try 1**:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(geopath) from geomet;
```

**Got an error**:

```
ERROR:  function st_intersects(geometry) does not exist
```

**Try 2**:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(cola,colb) from geomet;
```

**Got an error**:

```
ERROR:  function st_intersects(double precision, double precision) does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ST_Intersects](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) requires two geometries or two geometry fields, as you are checking for the intersection between one geometry and another or one set and another set.

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(geomA, geomB) FROM some_table;
```

or

```
SELECT a.id., b.id, ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM table a, table b 
WHERE a.id > b.id;
```

will give you all the pairwise intersection between two tables. Obviously, you can use ST_Intersects in a where clause in a similar fashion, to only return rows where the records from two different tables intersect.

Comment: Barca, Thank you so much. It will return `t` for true or `f` for false. But not `1` or `0`. I am right?

Comment: Yes, it returns a boolean, so t or f, which you could easily convert to 1/0, if you needed to, by use cast or the cast operator ::